# SELECT statement isn't returning any results when inner-joining three tables and selecting one column from two of them

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, inner-join

Goal: Write a query that will provide a list of Patrons who have borrowed books, and the books they have borrowed.

- `Book`: book_id, title, author_first
- `Patron`: name, phone, card_number
- `Loan`: card_number, Book_id, date_out, date_due

Here is the code I've come up with:

```
select 
    Patron.name,
    Book.title
from 
    Patron
inner join 
    Loan on Patron.Card_Number = Loan.card_number
inner join 
    Book on Loan.book_ID = Book.book_id
where 
    Loan.date_out is not null;
```

It returns the correct columns but it doesn't return any data.

[image: I have a screenshot of the tables here]

I'm using SSMS with SQL Server 2017 installed. I want it to reference the card number in the Patron table against the Loan table to see that this card number has taken a loan out, then select out the name of that book based on the book ID.

Comment: you can use  "convert(int,Loan.card_number)" when you joining Patron.Card_Number and Loan.card_number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `loan.card_number` is not same as `Patron.Card_Number` - that's why it is not showing any records
One way could be - `cast loan.card_number to int` like below -

```
select Patron.name,
    Book.title
    from Patron
        Inner Join Loan on Patron.Card_Number=cast(Loan.card_number as int)
        Inner Join Book on Loan.book_ID=Book.book_id
    where Loan.date_out is not null
```

Comment: This worked! Could you elaborate on how you knew that the loan.card_number wasn't the same as the patron_cardnumber? I checked sp_help on the tables and they have the same data type.

Comment: In your screenshot of the Loan table, the card_number is zero padded, appears to actually be a varchar field instead of an actual number column like it is in the other tables.

Comment: Just tested this, I could have sworn I entered as 0001 but I updated the field to 0001 and my original script started working. All the fields here were varchar, good eye. Thank you for pointing that out!